# Data map from one sheet to another using Conditional statement Python

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to map data from one dataframe to another using an conditional statement, but getting error while doing it .

Input Data:

```
amount
NaN
2100.05
3101
643
245
NaN
```

Code Snippet:

```
df =pd.read_excel(open(r'C:\Users\Desktop\data.xlsx', 'rb'), sheet_name='sheet1')
df2 =pd.read_excel(open(r'C:\Users\Desktop\data.xlsx', 'rb'), sheet_name='sheet2')

if df['amount'] == NaN:
    df2['expense'] = df2['full_exp'] = 00
else:
    df2['expense'] = df2['expense'] = 01

print(df['expense'])
```

Expected Output:

```
expense
00
01
01
01
01
00
```

Please suggest

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```py
df2['expense'] = np.where(df['amount'].isna(), df2['full_exp'], df2['expense'])
```

This will put the value of `df2['full_exp']` where `df['amount']` is NaN and  `df2['expense']` otherwise.

If you want to read more about `.isna()` and `np.where()` you can visit the [pandas.Series.isna](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isna.html) and [numpy.where](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) docs.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```py
import pandas as pd

import numpy as np

df =pd.read_excel(open(r'C:\Users\Desktop\data.xlsx', 'rb'), sheet_name='sheet1')

df2 =pd.read_excel(open(r'C:\Users\Desktop\data.xlsx', 'rb'), sheet_name='sheet2')

df2['expense'] = np.where(df['amount'].notnull(),'01',df2['expense'])

df2['expense'] = np.where(df['amount'].isnull(),'00',df2['expense'])

print(df2['expense'])
```